# TextUtil.concat not preserves hyperlinks

Tags: android

For example code below works right

```
CharSequence text = TextUtils.concat( "before ", Html.fromHtml( "<b>This works</b>"), " after " );
myTextView.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE );
```

If i put an hyperlink in the html code, i.e

```
CharSequence text = TextUtils.concat( "before ", Html.fromHtml( "<a href=\"www.google.it\">Google</a>"), " after " );
myTextView.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE );
Linkify.addLinks( myTextView, Linkify.ALL );
```

"Google" is displayed but hyperlink is not undelined correctly and is not clickable. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line `Linkify.addLinks( myTextView, Linkify.ALL );` and place the following line in between your `text` and `setText` declarations:

`classNameTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`

Comment: Worked putting classNameTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());after setText :) Thanks :)